# Use first column as header for csv

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv, cut

I have an input file as follows

```
hello: hello12
foo: bar14
test3: pppp
more: stuff
test14: bla
```

Is there a way to use the first column as header and separate it by comma's as follows:

```
hello,foo,test3,more,test14
hello12,bar14,pppp,stuff,bla
```

I've tried a few things at no success.

Comment: Are there more columns or just 2? Do the values contain `,` ? What are the few things you tried?

Comment: There are more but the idea is the same I think: I tried: `cut -d: -f1 file | tr '\n' ','`  but this will get first column onlu

Comment: From your example we cannot see how the next field will be separated.

Comment: @pLumo The first column which is in this example: `hello, foo, test3`  should be the header. Let me update the question. THe first column is seperated by a colon `:` and it doesn't matter how long the first column is, it should be used as the header.

Comment: When your real data contains more than 1 of anything, make sure your example contains more than 1 of that thing so it adequately demonstrates your problem and we have something we can test a potential solution against. In this case you're telling us in a comment that your real input has more than one data (non-header column) but your example only has one and consequently the one answer you have so far will only work for 1. Add at least 1 more column to your input and associated row to your output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of `cut` and `paste`:

```
paste -sd, <(cut -d: -f1 file) <(cut -d' ' -f2- file)
```

or use `awk`:

```
awk -F': ' 'NR==1{h=$1;v=$2}
            NR>1{h=h","$1;v=v","$2}
            END{print h;print v}
' file
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked well